# If 'a' is an integer array in C, why are 'a + 1' and '&a + 1' different?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a[2] = {0, 1};
    printf("%d\n",a);
    printf("&a + 1 %d\n",&a + 1);
    printf("a + 1 %d\n",a + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is as follows:

> 6422232
>
> &a + 1 6422240
>
> a + 1 6422236

Why are `&a + 1` and `a + 1` different?

Comment: You should not be using `%d` to print pointers, better use `%p`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `&a+1`, `&a` takes the address of the array. This yields a pointer to an array, so adding one adds the size of one array. This is because each type of pointer has its own unit of measurement—adding one always adds one of the pointed-to objects.

In `a+1`, `a` is the array itself. C automatically converts an array to the address of the first element. So, `a` yields a pointer to an element, so adding one adds the size of one element.

(In `&a+1`, `a` was not automatically converted to a pointer to the first element. Using `&` with an array is an exception to the conversion. See note 1 below.)

#### Notes

1. The automatic conversion of an array to a pointer to its first element occurs in most situations. It does not occur when the array is the argument of `sizeof`, `&`, or `_Alignof` or when the array is a string literal used to initialize an array.
2. In C’s model, a pointer uses units of whatever type of object it points to. So saying “adds the size of one array” is a bit imprecise. However, if we are talking about navigating storage using valid pointers in an array of objects, moving from one object to another traverses a number of bytes equal to the size of the object.
3. You should not print pointers with `%d`. The behavior of that is not defined by the C standard. To print a pointer, convert it to `void *` and print with `%p`:

   ```
   printf("%p\n", (void *) a);
   printf("&a + 1 %p\n", (void *) (&a + 1));
   printf("a + 1 %p\n", (void *) (a + 1));
   ```
4. Note that `%p` does not necessarily produce the actual memory address. The C standard allows an implementation to produce some other representation of the pointer. In good C implementations without complicated memory models, `%p` will print the memory address of the pointed-to object. However, this is a quality-of-implementation feature.

Comment: *"a pointer uses units of whatever type of object it points to"* - Almost. It would be more correct to say that the data that the pointer points at will be interpreted as X. The size of the units does not depend on what the pointer points at. Only the type of the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes though `a` and `&a` have same values. Their type is different. *In pointer arithmetic type matters.*

For example over here `a` decayed into pointer to first element(`int*`) in (`a+1`)and then it is incremented by `sizeof(int)`.

Where as `&a` is a case where decaying won't happen. So `&a` is of type `int (*)[2]` (pointer to an array of 2 `int` elements) now when you add to it `1` it moves by the size of the array or `2*sizeof(int)`.

This is why they are different.

Comment: All the answers posted here discusses everything. I upvoted those answers. This is just an answer on my own words.

Answer (score -1):

First to be very clear the name of array is a constant pointer to the array. So  it constantly points to address in memory where the array 1st element is store. The answer of &a+1  and a+1 differs cause the & a+1 what does its increments the address of array in normal words in increments the size of array and a + 1 prints you the value in addition of 1st element of the array

Comment: "name of array is a constant pointer to the array" No.  An array is not  pointer, a pointer is not an array.  In many contexts, similarities occur.